# Opening a detailed summary page when clicked on list tile

Tags: flutter

I have a todo app which has a listview with title and short summary showing when clicked on the listtile it should go to the particular todo details page which shows all the details regarding the todo
This is my listview

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: newdrawer(),
      appBar: newappbar(),
      body: _TaskList(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        foregroundColor: Colors.black54,
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        elevation: 0,
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {
          addDialog(context);
        },
      ),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
    );
  }

  // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
  Widget _TaskList() {
    if (Task != null) {
      return FlatButton(
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: Task.documents.length,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
          itemBuilder: (context, i) {
            return new ListTile(
              title: Text(Task.documents[i].data['Title']),
              subtitle: Text(Task.documents[i].data['Summary']),
            );
          },
        ),
        onPressed: () {},
      );
    } else {
      return Text('Loading, Please wait..');
    }
  }
}
```

the on pressesd button of flat button which is empty in widget tasklist when clicked should open the detailtask page showing only that particular task details

```
class _taskdetailState extends State<taskdetail> {
  //taskdetail([this.id]);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: newappbar(),
      drawer: newdrawer(),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('')
        ],
      )
    );
  }

}
```

Please help me in my guess in my list view the on pressesd when tapped should take the document id and then it should pass on to the detail screen. But i am out of thoughts on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

in onPressed method, you need to pass the detail of Task
like this

```
onPressed: (){
  navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder:(context)=>_taskdetailState(details: Task.documents[i].data)));
}
```

now you can access this data like

```
class _taskdetailState extends State<taskdetail> {
  final dynamic Taks;
  _taskdetailState({this.Task});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title:Text(Task.Title)),
      drawer: newdrawer(),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('')
        ],
      )
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: you have to do something like this @RavitejaReddy

Comment: I am getting an error , taskdetailstate is not defined for the class assisgned task state

Comment: great @RavitejaReddy

Comment: onTap: (){
              Navigator.push(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>
              taskdetail(Task.documents[i].data)
              )
              );
            },

Comment: i used the above code and in details page       title: Text(widget.documents[i]['Title']),

Comment: Why you are using i index you don't need it in detail page